# jQuery: blend in div-elements should smoothly expand auto-height of parent-div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Still new to jQuery, so: quick question. I have a div that holds various objects for a responsive portfolio weblayout. At first only 3 objects are shown, the rest are `display: none;` via CSS. With a button these invisible objects can then be blended in via JavaScript. The code kind of looks like this:

```
$('#maindiv').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.objects').fadeIn();
});
```

Works like it should, but since the `#maindiv` is set with `height: auto` in the CSS file, the height of the `#maindiv` just jumps as soon as the new objects begin to fade. A transition animation via CSS does not work apparenlty because of the `auto` value, which I need. So the question is: is there any way with JavaScript to make the height of the `#maindiv` somehow animate from the old auto-value to the new auto-value? Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, although its not 100% predictable / controllable how fast the animation rusn. You can just animate the max-height, that enables you to still use height: auto.

```
div {
max-height:1.2em;

-moz-transition: 1s;
-ms-transition: 1s;
-o-transition: 1s;
-webkit-transition: 1s;
transition: 1s;
```

}

[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/zwvNY/)

Comment: yeah I tried that before, but as you said, not really controllable. I would have to "guess" a lot since it could be just 10 or way over 30 elements blending in, then the the animation could kinda not ease-out since the max-height would have to be set way over the real height ... also the divs arrange differently with screen resize and so on. So for this problem of mine I would really need a way to "just" make the gap between the two auto-values animate I guess. But Thanks anyway :-)